# Force lowercase property names from Json() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Given the following class,

```
public class Result
{      
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning one of these in a Controller action like so,

```
return Json(new Result() { Success = true, Message = "test"})
```

However my client side framework expects these properties to be lowercase success and message.  Without actually having to have lowercase property names is that a way to achieve this thought the normal Json function call?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to implement a custom `JsonResult` like here:
[Creating a custom ValueType and Serialising with a custom JsonResult](https://web.archive.org/web/20100504160724/http://www.marcdormey.com/index.php/archives/300) *(original link dead)*.

And use an alternative serialiser such as [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), which supports this sort of behaviour, **e.g.:**

```
Product product = new Product
{
  ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2010, 12, 20, 18, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
  Name = "Widget",
  Price = 9.99m,
  Sizes = new[] {"Small", "Medium", "Large"}
};

string json = 
  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    product,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
    }
);
```

Results in

```
{
  "name": "Widget",
  "expiryDate": "\/Date(1292868060000)\/",
  "price": 9.99,
  "sizes": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This link works: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeContractResolver.htm

Comment: If you're using JSON.NET, and want not camelCase but snake_case, check out this gist, really helped me out! https://gist.github.com/crallen/9238178

Comment: How do I deserialize? Ex. from "small" to "Small"

Comment: @NiclasLindqvist For modern JSON.NET versions, there's a much simpler way to get snake_case: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm

Answer (score 21):

Changing serializer is simple if you are using Web API, but unfortunately MVC itself uses `JavaScriptSerializer` with no option to change this to use JSON.Net.

[James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801198/1185053) and [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22711526/1185053) give you the flexibility of JSON.Net but means that everywhere where you would normally do `return Json(obj)` you have to change to `return new JsonNetResult(obj)` or similar which if you have a big project could prove a problem, and also isn't very flexible if you change your mind on the serializer you want to use.

---

I've decided to go down the `ActionFilter` route. The below code allows you to take any action using `JsonResult` and simply apply an attribute to it to use JSON.Net (with lower case properties):

```
[JsonNetFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeJson()
{
    return Json(new { Hello = "world" });
}

// outputs: { "hello": "world" }
```

You can even set this up to automagically apply to all actions (with only the minor performance hit of an `is` check):

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
// ...
filters.Add(new JsonNetFilterAttribute());
```

---

#### The code

```
public class JsonNetFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is JsonResult == false)
            return;

        filterContext.Result = new CustomJsonResult((JsonResult)filterContext.Result);
    }

    private class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
    {
        public CustomJsonResult(JsonResult jsonResult)
        {
            this.ContentEncoding = jsonResult.ContentEncoding;
            this.ContentType = jsonResult.ContentType;
            this.Data = jsonResult.Data;
            this.JsonRequestBehavior = jsonResult.JsonRequestBehavior;
            this.MaxJsonLength = jsonResult.MaxJsonLength;
            this.RecursionLimit = jsonResult.RecursionLimit;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
                && String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("GET not allowed! Change JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.");

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            response.ContentType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;

            if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
                response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;

            if (this.Data != null)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    this.Data,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        });

                response.Write(json);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

With my solution, you can rename every property you want.

I've found part of the solution [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net) and on SO

```
public class JsonNetResult : ActionResult
    {
        public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }

        public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
        public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

        public JsonNetResult(object data, Formatting formatting)
            : this(data)
        {
            Formatting = formatting;
        }

        public JsonNetResult(object data):this()
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public JsonNetResult()
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.None;
            SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
              ? ContentType
              : "application/json";
            if (ContentEncoding != null)
                response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

            if (Data == null) return;

            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting };
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
```

So that in my controller, I can do that

```
        return new JsonNetResult(result);
```

In my model, I can now have:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Note that now, you have to set the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to every property you want to serialize.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is an old question, hope below code snippet will be helpful to others,

I did below with MVC5 Web API.

```
public JsonResult<Response> Post(Request request)
    {
        var response = new Response();

        //YOUR LOGIC IN THE METHOD
        //.......
        //.......

        return Json<Response>(response, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this setting to `Global.asax`, and it will work everywhere.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{   
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //....
         JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
         {
             var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
             {
                 ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                 PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                 Formatting = Formatting.None
             };

             return settings;
         }; 
         //....
     }
}
```