# How to tell Json.Net globally to apply the StringEnumConverter to all enums

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I want to deserialize enumerations to their string representation and vice versa with json.net. The only way I could figure out to tell the framework to apply its `StringEnumConverter` is to annotate the properties in question like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public virtual MyEnums MyEnum { get; set; }
```

However, in my use case, it would be much more convenient to configure json.net globally such that all enumerations get (de)serialized using the `StringEnumConverter`, without the need of extra annotations.

Is there any way to do so, e.g. with the help of custom `JsonSerializerSettings`?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Add a `StringEnumConverter` to the `JsonSerializerSettings` Converters collection.

Documentation: **[Serialize with JsonConverters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm)**

---

If you want the serializer to use camelCasing, you can set this as well:

```
SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
    new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

This will serialize `SomeValue` to `someValue`.

Comment: I tried setting this on my global.asax.cs under `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings`but didn't work. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Is there any way to lower-case the field name?  The CamelCaseText flag is hard-coded into the class and I don't see a way to use a different casing strategy.

Comment: @mikebridge Have you found a solution to this? Also looking for a way to set the name for each enum option myself (or use lowercase).

Comment: @Timm Yes, I used this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288660/net-ensuring-json-keys-are-lowercase/6288726#6288726

Comment: @mikebridge Thanks. I found that [EnumMember (Value = "undefined")] per enum entry works fine with JSON.Net as well (though unsupported by Microsoft's JSON deserializer)

Comment: @Timm If you want a finer-grain control you can also use a DataContract and then use a DataMember attribute, e.g. [DataMember(Name = "myfieldname")].

Comment: Answer is now out of date. V12 obsoletes "CamelCaseText". 'StringEnumConverter.CamelCaseText is obsolete. Set StringEnumConverter.NamingStrategy with CamelCaseNamingStrategy instead.'  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm

Answer (score 40):

The other answers work for ASP.NET, but if you want to set these settings generally for calling JsonConvert in any context you can do:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter {CamelCaseText = true});
    return settings;
});
```

(See http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data)

Comment: What I was looking for! Even shorter:
`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = { new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true } }
            };`

Comment: You saved me! Thanks bro! https://gist.github.com/regisdiogo/27f62ef83a804668eb0d9d0f63989e3e

Answer (score 18):

In your Global.asax.cs add

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add
                (new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

Comment: This solution seems to work perfectly for WebAPI serialization.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers are out of date as of Version 12.0.1. The new way is to use NamingStrategy. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm

```
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(
    new StringEnumConverter { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

For ASP.NET Core 2 do the following:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                });

        ...
```

Please note this is not `services.AddJsonOptions(...)`, it must be tagged onto MVC because you're creating settings for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Install the *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft* package.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
            {
                //CamelCaseText = true,//absolete
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            });
        });
 services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```