# Enum Serialization Json vs XML

Tags: .net, xml, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have following Enum in my project

```ccharp
public enum CameraAccessMethod
{
    Manual = 0,
    Panasonic = 1,
    Axis = 2,
    AirCam = 3
}
```

I have an object that is serialized either to json or to XML depending upon different scenarios and one of object's property is of type `CameraAccessMethod`. The problem i have is that when this property is serialized to XML it will give string representation of enum values (Manual, Panasonic,Axis,Aircam) but in JSON it is serialized to number values (0,1,2,3). How can i avoid this inconsistency? i want strings in JSON serialization as well.

Comment: How are you doing the JSON serialization? Depending on which serializer you use, it may or may not have an option of serializing enum values as strings.

Comment: I am using default serializer that ships with asp.net web api beta

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON serialization of c# enum as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since Web API RC you can get string representations of enums by applying a `StringEnumConvert` to the existing `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` converter collection during `Application_Start()`:

```ccharp
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
var enumConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
```

Comment: Needs a single `;` at the end of line 1

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily if you switch to using a formatter based upon Json.NET (which will ship out of the box with next drop of ASP.NET Web API).  See this SO post for details:

[How to tell Json.Net globally to apply the StringEnumConverter to all enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427909/how-to-tell-json-net-globally-to-apply-the-stringenumconverter-to-all-enums)

Answer (score 0):

To use `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`  and `enumConverter` both we can use below code. 
//code start here

```ccharp
var serializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
var enumConverter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter()
{
     IgnoreCase = true,
     SerializerSettings = serializerSettings
});
```