# Newtonsoft.Json DefaultSettings issue with F#

Tags: f#, json.net

Newtonsoft's Json library has the ability to set global settings to apply custom converters and other settings. I've got a custom converter that works as long as I call it explicitly for each object I serialize, but I would like to set it globally so I don't have to do that.  This can be done as shown here in C#:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121653/2506634

And the official signature of the DefaultSettings property is:

`public static Func<JsonSerializerSettings> DefaultSettings { get; set; }`

I've tried to translate this to F# like so:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = 
  System.Func<JsonSerializerSettings>
  (fun () ->           
    let settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    settings.Formatting <- Formatting.Indented
    settings.Converters.Add(new DuConverter())
    settings       
  )
  |> ignore
```

This compiles, and executes without error, but the custom converter is not applied when serializing. Also, for some reason setting the property returns a boolean (hence the `|> ignore` ) and I've noted that this boolean is false.

So, is something wrong with my translation to F#? Or is Newtonsoft perhaps ignoring my custom converter because the built in converter is being applied with precedence?

Comment: You're using `=`, which tests for equality (and then you're `ignore`ing the result).  You want to use `<-` to set the property instead.

Comment: @kvb maybe I should make this a separate question. Why did F# go with `=` for comparison instead of `==`?

Comment: If you find yourself using `ignore`, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @GuyCoder - When in doubt the answer is usually O'Caml compatibility.  Logically I think that this particular choice also makes more sense - why should the = symbol be associated with mutation?  But it does make the transition from C-style languages more difficult.

Comment: Ha! thanks. What a silly mistake.  @kvb if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you want to use the assignment operator (`<-`) instead of the equality operator (`=`).  Note that once you do this, the compiler will also apply the delegate conversion for you automatically (and there's no result to ignore), so your code can just become:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings <-
    fun () -> 
        let settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        settings.Formatting <- Formatting.Indented
        settings.Converters.Add(new DuConverter())
        settings
```