# Selecting a NamingStrategy when using a JsonConverter on a class property

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconverter

I've got a c# class that I am trying to correctly serialise using `Newtonsoft.Json`.  The property is an enumeration type and I wish the value to be serialised as the "lowercase version of the enumeration name".  There is a `JsonConverterAttribute` available for specifying this on the property and also a prewritten `StringEnumConverter` but I need to specify the [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm) on that converter but I can't work out the syntax.

I've tried to assign it on the property itself:

```
public class C
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter),NamingStrategy=typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public ChartType ChartType { get; set; }
}
```

and I've also tried adding it similarly onto the enumeration type itself:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter),NamingStrategy=typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public enum ChartType { Pie, Bar }
```

But the syntax is wrong.  I can't find any examples of this in the [Newtonsoft documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

The desired serialision would be: `"ChartType":"pie"` or `"ChartType":"bar"`

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, this appears to work:

```
[JsonProperty("type")] 
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter), 
     converterParameters:typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public ChartType ChartType { get; }
```

As [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_1.htm) is a property of the `StringEnumConverter` it's applied using the [`converterParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm) parameter.  This got my desired output.  I think an example of this would be useful in Newtonsoft documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution is using `JsonSerializerSettings`

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> {
        new StringEnumConverter(new CamelCaseNamingStrategy())
    }
};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for enabling camel casing on a single place in a .Net Core web api:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter), true)]
```

Note that you can append constructor parameters to the type given by the first parameter and `StringEnumConverter` has the following overloaded constructor:

```
StringEnumConverter(bool camelCaseText)
```

Of course, enabling this globally is normally preferred, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427909/how-to-tell-json-net-globally-to-apply-the-stringenumconverter-to-all-enums/7438186) for example.

Comment: For what it's worth, the boolean `camelCaseText` parameter used here has been marked obsolete. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter__ctor_2.htm