# Possibility of omitting default value for enum and excluding some enum properties from the OpenAPI spec

Tags: .net, enums, azure-functions, openapi

In order to create an OpenAPI spec for the Azure Functions I have been developing, I have used a library, which enables Azure Functions to render OpenAPI document and Swagger UI.
Generally, it works pretty well, but when it comes down to handling an enum within `[OpenApiParameter]`, I haven't been able to figure out how to customize it for the type of the parameter.

```
[OpenApiParameter(
        name: "levels",
        In = ParameterLocation.Query,
        Required = false,
        Type = typeof(List<LevelEnum>),
        Description = "List of levels"
        )]
```

By default, when converting an enum, the first index will be considered as the default enum property. However, in some cases, the enum properties are optional meaning that there should not be a default value.

Moreover, while coding I noticed that I was looking for a way to customize what should be included in the OpenApi Spec, but did not succeed in my research - I have tried using the annotations `[JsonIgnore]` and `[IgnoreDataMember]`, but that did not affect anything. I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/blob/main/docs/openapi-core.md#displayattribute) about how to show the string value of the enum properties, but unfortunately, it does always include everything and it is (seemingly) not possible to hand-pick, which should be included/excluded from the spec.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum LevelEnum
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    Bronze = 0, // This will always be the default value, but providing a level is optional

    Silver= 1,

    Gold = 2,

    Premium= 3,
}
```

Comment: for omitting default value (I would describe it also as showing all possible values) take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427909/how-to-tell-json-net-globally-to-apply-the-stringenumconverter-to-all-enums
for the other part I think would be better using a separate enum for the API

Comment: Yeah, I was also considering a separate enum, but thought that there might be a solution. Concerning omitting the default value, how is it omitted based on the answer? I would would like to omit it from the spec, as it is redundant - Programmatically the stated default value is null in my code.