# Encoding JSON from MVC view with lowercase keys?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following in my MVC view:

```
 $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new ProfileVm(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))));
```

This is working great, except all of the keys from `Model` are being encoded with uppercase first letters.  How can I invoke the camelCase resolver from the view?  Or is there a way to tell Json.Encode to use lowercase resolution?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288660/net-ensuring-json-keys-are-lowercase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **Newsoft JSON** for this:

```
@{ var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            Model, 
            Formatting.None, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }
   );

    $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new ProfileVm(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(json)))));
}
```

Comment: It is good, but isn't completely correct answer. It is better to use `new ProfileVm(@Html.Raw(@json)))` and put the java script statement **outside** the razor one.

Comment: For me this worked: 
var json = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject( Model, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }))));