# Send JSON via POST in C# and Receive the JSON returned?

Tags: c#, .net, json, httpwebrequest, json.net

This is my first time ever using JSON as well as `System.Net` and the `WebRequest` in any of my applications. My application is supposed to send a JSON payload, similar to the one below to an authentication server:

```
{
  "agent": {                             
    "name": "Agent Name",                
    "version": 1                                                          
  },
  "username": "Username",                                   
  "password": "User Password",
  "token": "xxxxxx"
}
```

To create this payload, I used the `JSON.NET` library. How would I send this data to the authentication server and receive its JSON response back? Here is what I have seen in some examples, but no JSON content:

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseUrl));
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";

string parsedContent = "Parsed JSON Content needs to go here";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

However, this seems to be a lot of code compaired to using other languages I have used in the past. Am I doing this correctly? And how would I get the JSON response back so I can parse it?

Thanks, Elite.

**Updated Code**

```
// Send the POST Request to the Authentication Server
// Error Here
string json = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createLoginPayload(usernameTextBox.Text, password)));
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // Error here
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL HERE", httpContent);
    if (httpResponse.Content != null)
    {
        // Error Here
        var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `WebClient.UploadString(JsonConvert.SerializeObjectobj(yourobj))` or `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I found myself using the [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) library to query RESTful APIs as the code is very straightforward and fully async'ed. To send this JSON payload:

```
{
  "agent": {                             
    "name": "Agent Name",                
    "version": 1                                                          
  },
  "username": "Username",                                   
  "password": "User Password",
  "token": "xxxxxx"
}
```

With two classes representing the JSON structure you posted that may look like this:

```cs
public class Credentials
{
    public Agent Agent { get; set; }
    
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

public class Agent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

You could have a method like this, which would do your POST request:

```cs
var payload = new Credentials { 
    Agent = new Agent { 
        Name = "Agent Name",
        Version = 1 
    },
    Username = "Username",
    Password = "User Password",
    Token = "xxxxx"
};

// Serialize our concrete class into a JSON String
var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

// Wrap our JSON inside a StringContent which then can be used by the HttpClient class
var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var httpClient = new HttpClient()
    
// Do the actual request and await the response
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost/api/path", httpContent);

// If the response contains content we want to read it!
if (httpResponse.Content != null) {
    var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
    // From here on you could deserialize the ResponseContent back again to a concrete C# type using Json.Net
}
```

Comment: perfect, but what is the await Task.run(()?

Comment: `Task.Run` is a shortcut since `.NET 4.5` for `Task.Factory.StartNew`. In this case I async'ify the serialization. You can obviously also do that synchronously. I just figured that, depending on the payload, it may take a bit longer, so I wouldn't want to waste unnecessary resources there.

Comment: You mean the HttpClient? Then yes, that's a library made by Microsoft!

Comment: I keep getting error on the lines that contain `await`. It says something about async methods.

Comment: Yes, you need to mark your method with the `async` modifier and the return type needs to be either `Task` (the equivalent for `void`) or `Task<T>` (the equivalent for `T`). e.g. `public async Task DoRequest() { /* ... */ }` or `public async Task<string> DoRequest() { /* ... */ return "hello world"; }`. What .NET version are you targeting with your project?

Comment: Let me post the current code i have right now in my question so you can get a better look. It is under Updated Code. I also added a comment `//Error here` where the errors where.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52445/discussion-between-kai-eichinger-and-elite-gamer)

Comment: In my codebase we inherit `StringContent` into a class `JsonContent`; the constructors take 1) string content, then call `base(content, Encoding.Utf8, "application/json")` and 2) string content, Encoding encoding, then make the appropriate `base()` call.

Comment: You shouldn't use Task.Run on synchronous CPU bound methods as you're just firing off a new thread for no benefit!

Comment: You don't have to type out the `JsonProperty` for every property. Just use Json.Net's built in [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) or a [custom `NamingStrategy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839347/3312114) to customize the serialization process

Comment: Side note: don't use a `using` with `HttpClient`. See: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: With System.Net.Http.Formatting you have extension methods defined:
"await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/domain", csObjRequest)"

Comment: Why don't you use `await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(payload)`?

Comment: If you want to skip the object serialization and use a string json you copied from elsewhere, you can escape the json into a string and then use it in the example above.   E.g.  `string stringPayload = "{\"test\": 123}";`

Answer (score 30):

Using the JSON.NET NuGet package and anonymous types, you can simplify what the other posters are suggesting:

```
// ...

string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    agent = new
    {
        name    = "Agent Name",
        version = 1,
    },

    username = "username",
    password = "password",
    token    = "xxxxx",
});

var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

// ...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the PostAsJsonAsync() method available in HttpClient()

```cs
var requestObj= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"endpoint",requestObj);
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation what your code does and how it solves the issue?

Comment: You can take whatever the object you want to post and serialize it using the   SerializeObject(); 

`var obj= new Credentials { 
    Agent = new Agent { 
        Name = "Agent Name",
        Version = 1 
    },
    Username = "Username",
    Password = "User Password",
    Token = "xxxxx"
};`

And then without having to convert it to httpContent, you can use the PostAsJsonAsync() passing the endpoint URL and the converted JSON object itself.

Comment: FYI there's no `PostAsJsonAsync()` on the `HttpClient` since .NET4.5 or so

Answer (score 9):

You can build your `HttpContent` using the combination of `JObject` to avoid and `JProperty` and then  call `ToString()` on it when building the `StringContent`:

```
        /*{
          "agent": {                             
            "name": "Agent Name",                
            "version": 1                                                          
          },
          "username": "Username",                                   
          "password": "User Password",
          "token": "xxxxxx"
        }*/

        JObject payLoad = new JObject(
            new JProperty("agent", 
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("name", "Agent Name"),
                    new JProperty("version", 1)
                    ),
                new JProperty("username", "Username"),
                new JProperty("password", "User Password"),
                new JProperty("token", "xxxxxx")    
                )
            );

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpContent = new StringContent(payLoad.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you avoid `Exception while executing function. Newtonsoft.Json: Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` errors?

Comment: An HttpClient instance is not supposed to create with using construct. The instance should be created once and used throughout the application. This is because it uses its own connection pool. Your code tend mostly to throw  SocketException. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

`System.Net.Http.Json.JsonContent` exists to make serializing into json very easy (that is, if you're not already using or unable to use convenience methods like `httpClient.PostAsync()`);

I was using `IDownstreamApi` with a `POST` method and needed to pass `HttpContent` so the code simply looks like:

```cs
        var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(request);
        using var response = await _downstreamApi.CallApiForAppAsync("GraphApi", options =>
        {
            options.RelativePath = "directoryObjects/getByIds";
            options.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post;
        }, jsonContent, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Deceptively easy to use. Works for JsonContent.Create(double[] {....}) as well. No need to mess around with any of the other arguments in the documentation