# C# post json object using httpWebRequst

Tags: c#, rest

I need to post an object in this format:

```
POST https://link
{
  "country": "nld",
  "emailaddress": "email@domain.com",
  "phone": "123",
  "notify_url": "https://asd.com"
}
```

I tried:

```
 var url = "URL";
            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + apiKey;


            var postData = "country" + Uri.EscapeDataString("hello");
            postData += "emailaddress" + Uri.EscapeDataString("world");
            postData += "phone" + Uri.EscapeDataString("123");
            postData += "notify_url" + Uri.EscapeDataString("d3wq");
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
 
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
```

But the server returns a 400 bad request. I think the data is in invalid format.

How can i alter my code to put the data into correct format ?

Thank you!

Comment: try change to `httpRequest.ContentType= "application/json";` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c

Comment: Usually in authorization headers, a bearer access token is supplied instead of an API key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post JSON to a server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585919/send-json-via-post-in-c-sharp-and-receive-the-json-returned

Comment: @Self holy sh*t there's a lot of bad code being heavily upvoted on this site. Look at the accepted answer on the second Q&A you link to. "`await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload))`"? Really? `StringContent`, `ReadAsStringAsync()`? The `PostAsJsonAsync()` extension method exists for over six years already.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Good catch. I just don't read most of the code. I can find dupe target without reading the question most of the time. I will try to give answers code a better look if theirs numbers is not too big. But a basic search query  return too many possible dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example request you show, shows a JSON request body, yet you tell the server in your HttpWebRequest that the incoming content-type is going to be a form post. But then you don't issue a form post, you post one long string:

```
countryhelloemailaddressworldphone123 // and so on
```

Don't use HttpWebRequest in 2021. It's a two decade old API that has more developer-friendly alternatives by now.

Use HttpClient instead, which has convenient (extension) methods for sending and receiving JSON:

```
var postModel = new
{ 
    country = "...", 
    emailaddress = "...", 
    ... 
}; 

var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(postModel);
```

You need to [install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158378/httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp) for that extension method.

If you insist you must use an `HttpWebRequest`, which I highly doubt, your question is answered in [How to post JSON to a server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145667/how-to-post-json-to-a-server-using-c), as that question and answer shows how to use that ancient API.

Comment: Than kyou. For serveral reasons, I have to use the webrequst. Can you show me how its done using this old api? :)

Comment: is httpclient from system..net.http? cause that one doesnt have postasjsonasync for me...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158378/httpclient-not-supporting-postasjsonasync-method-c-sharp. It's an extension method in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package.

Comment: Hello again; i gave urs a try again but I am always getting a bad request:
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var url = "url";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);


            var postModel = new
            {
                country = "asd",
                emailaddress = "asd@asd.de",
                phone = "123456",
                notify_url = "www.hello.com",
            };

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, postModel);

Comment: Then you need to consult said API's documentation to check why it won't accept that payload.

Comment: I seen that the server receives an empty request. How can it be empty`

Comment: I don't know. Check the request with Fiddler, and if that contains a payload, debug the server.

Comment: Thank you. Working with postman fixed the issue. Appeeantly, the API checked for the input values if they are valid e.g: is this a valid email, is this a valid phone number, etc. That was the last issue I had. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

Create object that you need to submit on your webrequest.

```
var xObject = new { xData = ... };
```

and after that use;

```
var newJsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(xObject);
```

**newJsonData** is a string as JSON format which you can post to your webrequest.