# How to send a post request with the C# client with a string as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send a string with a POST request.
[image]

however when I do this the parameter is still null
[image]

Comment: You can try write a class that contains message property. Then, create an instance of the class and set the message property equals "Message" value. Then pass the object instead of "Message" value like this,

var a = new A();
a.message = "Message";

await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(address, a);

Comment: Yes,I have found such examples,but I hoped there were better solutions for when only one parameter has to be sent.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post code as text instead

Comment: see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23586477/14973743) to send JSON as payload using HttpClient.  just sending "message" as shown by you doesn't send json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple scenario, you can pass the parameter in the URL with `PostAsync()` method. You don't need to create an extra object or anything

```
await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:60500/LogInfo?message=Test message", null);
```

Not sure if this is a good idea, but you can check another question here [HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)