# Force lowercase JSON serialization of dictionary keys while using camel case for class properties

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have the following property:

```
    [JsonProperty()]
    public Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> Foo { get; set; }
```

How can I use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to force the dictionary key to serialize in all lowercase?

For example, I'd like these keys to serialize the following way:

1. ABC1 -> abc1
2. DEF2 -> def2

My global configuration (Web API) uses the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, which results in the following serialization of above keys:

1. ABC1 -> abC1
2. DEF2 -> deF2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensuring json keys are lowercase in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288660/ensuring-json-keys-are-lowercase-in-net)

Comment: You can do so by writing a custom class of `DefaultContractResolver` just override `ResolveDictionaryKey` method to retrieve lowercase string.

Comment: @muaz - Got it. How would I then feed that new ContractResolver to the JsonProperty() attribute?

Comment: @tmaurst You cannot use the attribute for this. You need to have a custom resolver.

Comment: Alternative solution to what was mentioned already would be to replace your `Dictionary` with another class, and in that class define the keys with `JsonProperty` attribute names that are lowercase. This would only work if the keys in your `Dictionary` are always static (and known ahead of time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by implementing a custom `NamingStrategy` deriving from the `CamelCaseNamingStrategy`.  It's just a few lines of code:

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy : CamelCaseNamingStrategy
{
    public CustomNamingStrategy()
    {
        ProcessDictionaryKeys = true;
        ProcessExtensionDataNames = true;
        OverrideSpecifiedNames = true;
    }

    public override string GetDictionaryKey(string key)
    {
        return key.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Then replace the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` in your Web API global configuration with a `DefaultContractResolver` which uses the new naming strategy:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
    new DefaultContractResolver() { NamingStrategy = new CustomNamingStrategy };
```

Here is a working demo (console app): https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVRiJY

Note: naming strategies *are* supported via `[JsonProperty]` and `[JsonObject]` attributes in Json.Net, but sadly the dictionary keys don't appear to get processed when you apply the strategy that way.  At least [it did not seem to work in my testing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WPBgun).  Setting the strategy via resolver seems to be the way to go for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This code just making the property names lower case not camel case!
key.ToLower();

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh The OP asked that dictionary keys be all lower case, while everything else be camel case.  So that is what this code does.  See the example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVRiJY

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 builder.Services.AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

        // this line
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });
```