# i have the C# model class , and i want to save the same properties(key) in mongodb in small case

Tags: c#, mongodb

my C# class

```
public class User
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

my mongodb json document

***{
"_id": {
"$oid": "63353few87yr8748wd8"
},
"Name": "Rishabh",
"Email": "Rishabh@gmail.com"
}***

expected json

*****{
"_id": {
"$oid": "634376t7tegr78145d8"
},
"name": "Rishabh",
"email": "Rishabh.soni2@honeywell.com"

}*****

I want the property in small case is there any solution for it
I have already tried with changing the class property by Name to name it worked but I don't want that way I just need to save the key name in small letter not the class property name.
Please suggest any solution for it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to lowercase them, or that you want to camelCase them? Would ThisPropertyName become thispropertyname or thisPropertyName?

Comment: Depending on what you want, you'll either need to register `CamelCaseElementNameConvention`, or make your own name convention (for all lowercase).

Comment: The answer here may have what you are looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288660/ensuring-json-keys-are-lowercase-in-net

Answer (score 0):

By default, MongoDB maps the property names as they are to the BSON property names. If it is only about some properties that you want to change, you can mark them with `BsonElement` attributes and specify the name, e.g.

```
public class User
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
    [BsonElement("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

However, if you want to change the naming convention in one place, you can use the `CamelCaseElementNameConvention` like this at the beginning of your application:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
ConventionRegistry.Register(
 "CamelCaseElementNameConvention",
 pack,
 t => t.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace."));
```

See this [link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/) for details.