# How do you handle differing naming conventions when serializing C# objects to JSON?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, naming-conventions

I am using ASP.Net to serialize classes designed in C# to JSON. My Javascript application then requests those objects with AJAX. I have done this on a couple of projects now, but I run into the problem that the C# standard naming conventions use PascalCase for the public members, and in Javascript they are generally camelCase.

This particularly becomes an issue when I have some Javascript-only classes that use camelCase and some mixed-use classes that use PascalCase since I designed them in C# originally.

How does everyone else deal with this sort of problem? Do you just pick one or the other? If so which one is more broadly chosen? Or is there perhaps a clever way to user a JSON serializer to switch between the two naming conventions?

Comment: That is definitely a matter of opinion. adrift and TerryR are both right. It's a matter of preference more than anything. I personally do it the way TerryR suggests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use JSON.net to serialize the data for you, and you can even tell it to use camelCase.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2789593/435460) asks something similar.  Here's a code example for reference:

```
Product product = new Product {
    ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2010, 12, 20, 18, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), Name = "Widget", Price = 9.99m, Sizes = new[] {
        "Small", "Medium", "Large"
    }
};

string json =
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    product, 
    Formatting.Indented, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

Don't worry about the performance of JSON.net either, as [the performance of it versus native serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison.aspx) is comparable (better in most cases).

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, you can specify the name using the `DataMemberAttribute.Name` property:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "user_name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

will serialize to

```
{"user_id":123,"user_name":"John Doe"}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just use what the server gives me.

C#

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(data) {
       var person = data;    
       alert(person.Name);
   }
});
```