# JSON.NET Deserializing Different Property Names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there an automatic way in Json.NET to automatically map JSON properties from lower case underscore to pascal case no underscore.  I know you can add json attributes to each property but is that the only way?

My JSON is like this:

```
{
    "first_name": "Roger",
    "last_name": "The Shrubber"
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public FirstName { get; set; }
    public LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I voted to close but I didn't read carefully enough. Sorry about that. Please disregard.

Comment: If I recall correctly there is an attribute for that. Something like `JsonProperty("first_name")`. I can't remember the exact name. You'll have to check on that.

Comment: @EBrown: He mentions putting attributes on each property

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker My mistake. I didn't see that part.

Comment: You can do so by overriding the contract resolver, see [C# JSON.NET convention that follows Ruby property naming conventions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922874/), [How do you handle differing naming conventions when serializing C# objects to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482668/), and so on. Search for "JSON.NET naming convention" for some implementations. See for example [Json.NET contract resolver that uses Ruby-style lowercase with underscore naming conventions](https://gist.github.com/crallen/9238178) on GitHub.