# Data received from angularjs to MVC controller is null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Dears, I have two classes Master and detail named by Raterequest and Raterequestdetails. I have created a viewmodel contains both of them.
in Angularjs i have an object contains rate and a list contains orderdetails.
when i debug the controller the data received is null for both 
here is the code

Rate request class

```
 public class RateRequests
{
    public int RateRequestsID { get; set; }
    public DateTime RateRequestsDate { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestName { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestType { get; set; }
    public string RateRequestMode { get; set; }


}
```

Rate request details class

```
public class RateRequestsLines
{
    public int RateRequestsLinesID { get; set; }
    public int RateRequestsID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RateRequestsID")]
    public virtual RateRequests RateRequestsFK { get; set; }
    public short FCLCNTRS { get; set; }
    public short FCLCNTRSSIZE { get; set; }
    public string FCLCNTRSTYPE { get; set; }

}
```

Rate request view model

```
public class RateRequestViewModel
{
    public RateRequests rate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RateRequestsLines> ratelines { get; set; }
}
```

Angularjs

```
var linkers = angular.module("linkers", [])
.service("linkersSrv", function ($http) {

    var urlBase = "/LinkersEgypt/";

    this.save = function (url, ratee) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: urlBase + "/" + url,
            data: ratee,
            ̶a̶s̶y̶n̶c̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶,̶
        })

    };

})
```

```
.controller("linkersCon", function ($scope, linkersSrv) {

    $scope.fcl = [];

    $scope.addFCL = function () {
        $scope.fcl.push({ FCLCNTRS: $scope.ncntrs, FCLCNTRSSIZE: $scope.csize, FCLCNTRSTYPE: $scope.ctype });
        console.log($scope.fcl);
    }

    $scope.save = function () {

        var ratee = {
            rate: {
                RateRequestsDate: $scope.rdate,
                RateRequestName: $scope.rname,
                RateRequestType: $scope.rtype,
                RateRequestMode: $scope.smode
            },
            RateRequestsLines: $scope.fcl
        };

        console.log(ratee);
        var promisepost = linkersSrv.save("RateRequest/AddAllRate", ratee);
        promisepost.then(function () {
            toastr.success("Successfully saved");

        })

    }
})
```

Rate controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddAllRate (RateRequestViewModel rate)
    {
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

Any help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding `[FromBody]`: `AddAllRate ([FromBody] RateRequestViewModel rate)`, since binding should be performed against request body not request params.

Comment: check JsonSerializerSettings in project [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789593/force-lowercase-property-names-from-json-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: [FromBody] is raising an error " Attribute could not be found

Comment: can you explain more how to check jsonserializer on my code

Comment: `async` is not a recognized property of the $http service config object.

Comment: Please specify the version of MVC you are using.

Comment: MVC 5 entity framework 6

Comment: Hello any help...